# How to specify servlet version in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to specify servlet version in a spring boot application which does not have a web.xml?
I actually need to use servlet 3.0 and not 3.1 which is default for spring boot latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the embedded tomcat version (if you are using) to govern the servlet spec version. Setting it like below makes the spring boot run in tomcat 7.x which has a default servlet spec of 3.0

```
<properties>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```